# What is the purpose of having user account separation between SO meta SU etc?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we need the trilogy instead of just one site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/why-do-we-need-the-trilogy-instead-of-just-one-site)

Some of my questions on SO got shipped over to meta and SU. Then I had to make accounts over there. Seems like an avoidable complication. There must be some logical reason for this, no?

Comment: Welcome to Meta, Flotsam! Your question has been asked before. In addition to the link above, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6070 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6848/one-stackoverflow-to-rule-them-all http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36281/why-are-there-so-many-sites-in-the-stack-overflow-trilogy

Comment: Sortof. Start my points over (if you must), but why make me do another account. If the sites are connected enough for users to port my questions over, why isn't it connected enough to port my account over (minus the points)?

Comment: @Popular Demand, this is not about combining the sites, but having only one account between the sites.

Comment: @Jon, okay. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12571/automatically-create-accounts-in-all-sister-sites Rel: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/single-location-for-so-sf-su-user-info http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9502/one-account-for-so-meta-serverfault-and-superuser-except-reputation-and-badges

Comment: @Popular, First 2 questions are asking about automatic linking rather than just one account, the other 2 are duplicates, however since they were asked in 2009 there were not all the SE sites.

Comment: @Jon, ah, but that's the beauty of the SE model! Old answers out of date? Comment on them, downvote if it's really bad, post a new answer with the now-correct info and watch the rep roll in! I'll even bump the last one for you by editing it for grammar.

Answer (score 2):

You have two separate accounts because they are two different sites.

If you have a high rep on Stackoverflow it generally means that the community trust/agree with your questions/answers.  That doesn't mean that your question/answers will be as, for want of a better word, accepted on Meta.Stackoverflow The same goes for other sites in the trilogy - I wouldn't expect the same amount of rep on SuperUser as I have Stackoverflow.  I would have to earn it.

From the `About` for Meta

> This site is for meta-discussion of a family of Q&A websites, all based on the Stack Exchange engine.
>
> ### What the heck is meta-discussion?
>
> Let's ask our [friends at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-discussion):
>
> > Meta-discussion means discussion of the discussion itself
> >         instead of the actual topic of the discussion. For example:
> >
> > - the style of a discussion
> > - its participants
> > - the setting in which the discussion occurs
> > - the relationship of the discussion to other discussions on the same or different
> >               topics.
> >
> > The etymology for the "meta-" prefix dates back to Aristotle's  
> >             [Metaphysics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics_(Aristotle)), which came after his works on physics. The fundamental meaning
> >         of the prefix in Greek is simply "after."

And from the `FAQ` for Stackoverflow

> ### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers,
>     people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions
>     have a bit of **source code** in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - matters that are *unique* to the programming profession
>
> … then you're in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Please look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even
>     answered!) before you ask. It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your
>     own question, as long as you pretend you're on  
>     [Jeopardy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!): phrase it in the form of a question.

As `meta.stackoverflow` serves a purpose for sites based on StackExchange I think it has been mentioned that the name should be changed - I think we are too far gone for that, however that a different discussion all together.

Comment: I read the faq regarding earning credibility, yet these "sites" are connected enough for people just to whiz bang my questions over somewhere else where I have to create another account? OK, start my credibility points over there (maybe that makes sense) but the different accounts is puzzling to me.

Comment: the question is not neccessarily about combinign rep points, but about having a single account (with different rep for each site)

Answer (score 1):

I think we should ahve the same account for all sites, but just different amounts of rep, so that if you link your OpenID to an SO account you don't have to do linking or logging in on any others site.

Comment: Yes, that is my question. I should have left out the part about cool points. If you can port my question somewhere else, I shouldn't have to make an account there too. I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

To put some perspective in this: The "avoidable complication" you speak of is *one whole mouse click*.

With the recent addition of [global login](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/), the whole "several accounts on several sites" issue has been made a whole lot easier, and given the growth of the network, I don't expect the efforts to stop here.

But it's not like you have to accept another 64 KByte EULA, followed by a quiz checking that you really read it, go through a credit check, and sign an NDA, just to create an account.

It's *one click*.

Comment: No necessarily, if you switch from one SE site to another it doesn't always remember youre logged in, so you go to ask a question and after having typed everything out, you realise your not logged in, so you have to open a new tab to the ask a question page after logging in and then copy everything across.

Comment: Another thing, my username on other sites is Jonathan, I haven't ever changed it manually, but for some reason here its Jon.

Comment: @Jon Neither of your two comments has anything to do with this question, let alone my answer. Why are you posting them here?

Comment: I'm just saying its not always only one mouse click that is makes it complicated.