# Why other meta sites not required to create account?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, user-accounts, per-site-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of having user account separation between SO meta SU etc?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66053/what-is-the-purpose-of-having-user-account-separation-between-so-meta-su-etc)
>   [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

I have accounts on 10-12 sites of SE.

1. Why do I have to create an account on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/
2. Why don't I have to create an account on other meta sites? They simply take all credentials from the main site's account account? This happens for me e.g. on these sites:

   - http://meta.serverfault.com/
   - http://meta.superuser.com/
   - https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mostly for historical reasons. Meta.SO also doubles as the "super-meta" for the whole network, so it doesn't make sense for its reputation to be linked to another site.

However, [there are plans to change this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange). When this change is implemented, Meta.SO will function exactly like meta sites on other sites, and Meta.SE will be the new "super-meta" which will have its own registration and reputation.

Comment: Then what will happen to reputation and badges of MSO?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: I believe the plan is to transfer that rep to MSE, and then the rep on MSO will be linked to your SO rep like it is on the other sites.

Comment: And questions present on MSO will be migrated also?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Try clicking the link provided in the answer.